# Collateral effect using the sprintf function

Tags: c

How come when I use the `sprintf` function somehow the variable `A` value changed?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    short int A = 8000;

    char byte_1[2] /*0001 1111 01000 0000*/, total[4]; 
    sprintf(byte_1, "%i", A);
    printf("%s\n", byte_1);// displayed on the screen 8000
    printf("%i\n", A); // displayed on the screen 12336
}
```

Comment: Buffer overflow?  `byte_1` can only hold a single digit and a null byte, but formatting `A` requires 5 bytes (4 digits, one null byte).  You have undefined behaviour; anything can happen.

Comment: The quick answer is: avoid UBs and do not ask why when you invoke the UB you get something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`byte_1` is too short to receive the representation of `A` in decimal: it only has space for 1 digit and the null terminator and `sprintf` does not have this information, so it will attempt to write beyond the end of the `byte_1` array, causing undefined behavior.

- make `byte_1` larger, 12 bytes is a good start.
- `sprintf` is inherenty unsafe. Use `snprintf` that protects against buffer overrun:

  ```
  snprintf(byte_1, sizeof byte_1, "%i", A);
  ```

Here is a potential explanation for this unexpected output: imagine `byte_1` is located in memory just before `A`. `sprintf` converts the value of `A` to five characters `'8'`, `'0'`, `'0'`, `'0'` and `'\0'` that overflows the end of `byte_1`, and overwrites the value of variable `A` itself. When you later print the value of `A` with `printf`, `A` no longer has value `8000`, but rather `12336`... Just one of an infinite range of possible effects of undefined behavior.

Try this corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    short int A = 8000;
    char byte_1[12], total[4]; 

    snprintf(byte_1, sizeof byte_1, "%i", A);
    printf("%s\n", byte_1);
    printf("%i\n", A);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: probably, `A` was somewhere shortly after `byte_1` in memory, so when `byte_1` overflowed, `A`s value was altered.  Note that this isn't a "collateral effect" of sprintf, it's an inherent danger in C and something _you_ caused when you told `sprintf` to write to `byte_1` without allocating proper space at `byte_1` beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

The text representation of the value stored in `A` is `”8000”` - that’s four characters *plus* the string terminator, so `byte_1` needs to be *at least* 5 characters wide.  If you want `byte_1` to store the representation of any unsigned int, you should make it more like 12 characters wide:

```
char byte_1[12];
```

Two characters is not enough to store the string `”8000”`, so when`sprintf` writes to `byte_1`, those extra characters are most likely overwriting `A`.

Also note that the correct conversion specifier for an unsigned int is `%u`, not `%i`.  This will matter when trying to format very large unsigned values where the most significant bit is set.  `%i` will attempt to format that as a negative signed value.

**Edit**

As chrqlie pointed out, the OP had declared `A` as `short int` - for some reason, another answer had changed that to `unsigned int` and that stuck in my head.  Strictly speaking, the correct conversion specifier for a `short int` is `%hd` if you want signed decimal output.

For the record, here's a list of some common conversion specifiers and their associated types:

```
Specifier        Argument type        Output
---------        -------------        ------
      i,d                  int        Signed decimal integer
        u         unsigned int        Unsigned decimal integer
      x,X         unsigned int        Unsigned hexadecimal integer
        o         unsigned int        Unsigned octal integer
        f        float, double        Signed decimal float
        s               char *        Text string
        c                 char        Single character
        p               void *        Pointer value, implementation-defined
```

For `short` and `long` types, there are some length modifiers:

```
Specifier        Argument type        Output
---------        -------------        ------
       hd                short        signed decimal integer
      hhd                 char        signed decimal integer
       ld                 long        signed decimal integer
      lld            long long        signed decimal integer
```

Those same modifiers can be applied to `u`, `x`, `X`, `o`, etc.

Comment: Your remark is about `%u` vs `%i` is true but `A` is a `short int`, not an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @chqrlie: =sigh= - was looking at another answer where it was changed to `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

`byte_1` is too small for the four digits of "A". It only has enough room for a single digit, and the null (`\0`) terminator. If you make `byte_1` an array of 5 bytes, one for each digit and the null byte, it will be able to fit "A".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    unsigned int A = 8000;

    char byte_1[5], total[4]; 
    sprintf(byte_1, "%i", A);
    printf("%s\n", byte_1);
    printf("%i\n", A);

    return 0;
}
```

Basically, messing around with memory and trying to put values into variables that are too small for them, is undefined behavior. This is legal but objectively dangerous in C, and no program should be accessing memory like this.

Comment: You are not addressing the question. Why don't you change everything to **char** I change 8000 to 255?  ALSO notice that unsigned integer requires the **u** specifier as **i** is just not proper.

Answer (score -5):

`sprintf(byte_1, "%i", A);`

Format specifier **needs** to agree to the variable type.

I suggest the following change:

`sprintf(byte_1, "%c", A);
printf("%c\n", byte_1);`

---

**EDIT:** So an additional change after performing the change above, is to also change `A` so it is of the same type as `byte_1`. This will force you to change the value in your example to match the range of char types. Notice that using a function to protect you for overflowing is just a bad solution. Instead, it is **your responsibility** as a designer of this code to choose the proper tools for the job. When working with char variables, you need to use char-like containers. Same goes with integers, floats, strings, etc. If you have a 1 kilogram of sugar, you want to use a 1kg container to hold this amount. You wouldn't use a cup (250g) as, as you see, it overflows. Happy codding in C!

Comment: `%c` has completely different semantics, and anyway `A` is too wide to be a `char` (on most architectures).

Comment: @rici The code was tested. Also we would agree that short and char are the same size. Finally, looking at the OP code, he is learning... I bet your approach, although technical, do not really address the subtlety of this question. -Kf

Comment: `short` must be at least 16 bits while `char` is normally 8 bits, so they are not the same size. And I haven't presented an approach, but I basically agree with chqrlie that `snprintf` is appropriate.

Comment: That is a double failure there. **Normally** is just showing you are not sure. You don't even now if the OP is operating in a 32 or 64bit architecture? And from a teaching perspective, @chqrlie's answer is not appropriate. -Kf

Comment: Using `sprintf` is **unsafe** due to to being subject to **buffer overruns**.   No one has been using it for over a decade.  Use `snprintf` as mentioned by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51804433/585968) above